# Why am I getting a FileNotFoundException here?

Tags: python, file, exception, filenotfoundexception

Just trying to batch download some past papers from an exam website whilst improving my programming skills. I've researched quite a lot of things and don't know why this isn't working.

Error:

```
Downloading C:\Users\Azmat\Desktop\Practise Exams\Biology\January 2012 Question Paper.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testDownloader.py", line 31, in <module>
    with open(filename, 'w+') as code:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Azmat\\Desktop\\Practise Exams\\Biology\\January 2012 Question Paper.pdf'
```

My code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

years = [12, 13]
months = ["JAN", "JUN"]
subjects = ["BL", "CH", "PH"]
files = ["QP", "W-MS", "WRE"]
sub = {
    'BL': 'Biology',
    'CH': 'Chemistry',
    'PH': 'Physics',
}
mon = {
    'JAN' : 'January',
    'JUN' : 'June',
}
fil = {
    'QP' : 'Question Paper',
    'W-MS' : 'Mark scheme',
    'WRE' : "Examiner's report"
}

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        for subject in subjects:
            for file in files:
                url =('http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-%s1HP-%s-%s%d.PDF' % (subject, file, month, year))
                filename = 'C:\\Users\\Azmat\\Desktop\\Practise Exams\\' + sub[subject] + '\\' + mon[month] + ' 20%d ' % year + fil[file] + '.pdf' 
                print("Downloading " + filename) 
                f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
                data = f.read()
                with open(filename, 'w+') as code:
                    code.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you are writing the file to has to exist before opening the file for writing. You can use `os.mkdir` for a single directory or `os.makedirs` to recursively create directories.

```
import os
for subject in sub.values():
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\Azmat\\Desktop\\Practise Exams\\' + subject)
```